# How to apply two materials+textures to the same object using UV Map

Tags: texturing, materials, unity

I have created a UV map and used Gimp to apply two different sets of textures on two different layers.

I've returned to Blender and created two materials, and assigned one layer of textures to each material.

I can apply them individually to the object, but I want to apply them both at the same time.  Is this possible?  How do I do so?

Ideally I'd like to be able to do it by overlayering the two I have, as they fill different parts of the mesh.  In other words, I don't want to have to select individual faces and apply the respective material, because it's a complicated shape with about 7k faces.

If relevant, ultimately I wish to be able to export the two materials into Unity for use there.  I want to be able to set different settings on them in Unity, which is why there's two of them.  i.e. I don't want to bake them in Blender.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello Altissimus
How you about to use a UV aligned B&W mask ?

Comment: Hi Ruben,  could you please point me to a good tutorial of which you speak?  I can't find anything from a search.